# linux WoWLAN: making it work after disconnections and AP outages

Tags: linux, wifi

i have simple requirement: remotely access my linux (ubuntu 22.04 base) desktop replacement. this entails remotely accessing my router and sending a WoL packet over wifi then logging into my PC, which works.

the problem is, my PC wakes up when i do not want it to.

although intel feels it needs to sneak several always-on trojan horse black boxes into our PCs (intel ME, the EC, the SMM), it apparently was too much to ask of the wlan adapter for it to be able to reconnect to the wifi when connection was lost during standby (because, you know, that would have actually been useful to PC owners for a change).

so the solution is to have the wowlan-capable wlan adapter to wake on magic packet as well as on lost wifi connection, so the OS can then reconnect.

so again, this is what i need: to be able to remotely wake up my PC.

AFAICT, this entails:

- set up WoWLAN and sleep.
- on wake up, have the PC check why it woke up:

  - if it was a magic packet or any other wake up trigger, we are done.
  - if it was a connection loss:

    - try reconnecting for some time. if successful, go to sleep again.
    - else the lights might have gone out, the router is temporarily gone, and we are running on battery. so lets use something like rtcwake to sleep for a while, then wake up and retry the connection and so on. we can even do some exponential backoff here to save battery. alternatively, we could check the AC adapter and rtcwake-sleep for a while and retry until the AC power comes back, and only then wait for wifi reconnection before sleeping again. the point being that if the router is out, we probably should be sleeping anyway, to save battery and because there is nothing to talk to anyway.

this is kinda trivial and seems to be something a lot of users might want to do. i seriously do not believe that this has not been solved already and that i need to start fiddling with systemd and scripts.

which are my options? i am inclined to add a silly router in wifi station mode with a silly USB ethernet adapter... so wasteful!

my older desktop replacement (DELL) could be woken up by AC start (even from power off, and of course by wired WoL too), which would have given me more options, but these consumer laptops are total crap (lenovo).

other non-wowlan solutions could help too, like waking the PC for a minute every few hours, which would force a reconnect if necessary and save battery if not explicitly woken.

are there some ready-made solutions out there?

EDIT:

another solution: only after waking up due to loss of connection, wait for a minute for reconnection and if successful go to sleep. otherwise rtcwake-sleep for a while, then retry.

which begs the question: what about race conditions? what if we set to sleep after reconnection (or we are about to sleep for the first time) and the connection is lost while we enter sleep? is this all as brittle as it looks?